# How to mutate sum by factor?

Tags: r, sum, dplyr

I have a dataset that I am working on and need to sum up the amount by year. I would like to create a separate variable that sums up the amount just from one factor of another variable (example is just the United States amounts). Below is what I have to do these separately, how could I combine this code together?

```
country year donor amount
china 2000 germany 20
china 2000 france 30
china 2000 united states 40 
china 2000 united states 50
china 2001 germany 20
china 2001 france 30
china 2001 united states 40 
china 2001 united states 50
china 2002 germany 20
china 2002 france 30
china 2002 united states 40 
china 2002 united states 50

new.data <- old.data %>%
  group_by(country, year) %>%
  summarise(sum.amount = sum(amount)) %>%

new.data <- old.data %>%
  filter(donor == "United States")
  group_by(country, year) %>%
  summarise(us.amount = sum(amount)) %>%
```

Comment: `group_by(donor, country, year)`

Comment: Or create a new grouping category: `group_by(US_donor=ifelse(donor=="United States", "U.S.", "Non-U.S."), country, year)`.

Comment: This does work in summing the amount by donor. However, I am still having problem creating a new variable with the total sum for all donors in that country year as well as a variable with the total sum of us donations in that country year.

Comment: I edited the original example data. The expected output that I would be looking for would be "country" "year" "total amount" "us amount". This way for every country year, there is a total amount from all donors and a total us amount just from the us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join the two queries with `inner_join`:

```
library(dplyr)

new.data = old.data %>%
  group_by(country, year) %>%
  summarise(sum.amount = sum(amount)) %>%
  inner_join(old.data %>%
         filter(donor == "united states") %>%
         group_by(country, year) %>%
         summarise(us.amount = sum(amount)))
```

or use `mutate` for the first aggregation, and `filter` + `summarize` for the second. This second method should be much faster for large datasets, since there is only one pass of `old.data`, and you are reducing it's size along the way:

```
new.data = old.data %>%
  group_by(country, year) %>%
  mutate(sum.amount = sum(amount)) %>%
  filter(donor == "united states") %>%
  summarize(sum.amount = max(sum.amount), 
            us.amount = sum(amount))
```

**Note:**

`mutate(sum.amount = sum(amount))` creates the same `sum.amount` rows within the same country year combination. `summarize` then creates `us.amount` by summing up `amount` within each country year combination for US `donors` only. If in this step, I only wrote `summarize(us.amount = sum(amount))`, `sum.amount` column will be lost. But since I am aggregating by country year, I have to also use an aggregating function for `sum.amount` to include it. `max(sum.amount)` does the job because all `sum.amount`s are the same within the same country year combination. Likewise, `min(sum.amount)` would also work.

**Result:**

```
# A tibble: 3 x 4
# Groups:   country [?]
  country  year sum.amount us.amount
   <fctr> <int>      <int>     <int>
1   china  2000        140        90
2   china  2001        140        90
3   china  2002        140        90
```

**Data:**

```
old.data = structure(list(country = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "china", class = "factor"), 
    year = c(2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 
    2001L, 2002L, 2002L, 2002L, 2002L), donor = c("germany", 
    "france", "united states", "united states", "germany", "france", 
    "united states", "united states", "germany", "france", "united states", 
    "united states"), amount = c(20L, 30L, 40L, 50L, 20L, 30L, 
    40L, 50L, 20L, 30L, 40L, 50L)), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("country", 
"year", "donor", "amount"), row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

Comment: thanks for the help. I've gone ahead and gotten exactly what I was looking for. I had a clarification question though. What is the purpose of the `max(sum.amount)`?

Comment: @TomOkal Glad that my answer helped. See my updated Note section for explanation.